# React Native w/ firebase "undefined is not an object"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Getting this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'doc.data().books')
```

from this code:

```
    const getData = () => {
        const snapshot = db.collection('users').doc(userEmail).onSnapshot((doc) => {
            setData(doc.data().books)
        })

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getData()
    }, [])
```

this is the firestore database, trying to get to the updated boo collection (gets shown in a flatlist that needs to get updated when new content is added to the collection) Note that there's a users collection that is offscreen.

[image]
I'm pretty sure it's something that I'm doing wrong on my snapshot but I'm really not sure what, all help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I guess that either `doc` or the return value from `doc.data()` are undefined. Try debugging them one at a time and see which one is undefined, and work from there.

Comment: Are you trying to get the documents of the `boo` or `books` subcollections?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `doc.data()` returned undefined, which means the document you requested doesn't exist.  You probably passed a value for `userEmail` other than what you expected it to be.  Since you didn't show the value, we don't know for sure what went wrong.

I will point out that document IDs must be exact matches, so if the email address wasn't exactly "Email@email.com" with a capital E, the query will not return a document using what you've shown here.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities. However, db is not defined within the scope of the getData function... where is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, you want to get the documents in the `books` (or `boo`?) subcollection of the user document with id corresponding to `userEmail`.

If this assumption is correct, you should do as follows:

```
const getData = () => {
    db.collection('users').doc(userEmail).collection('books')
       .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
           var books = [];
           querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
               books.push(doc.data());
           });
           // Here you have an array of all the book objects.
           // It's up to you to use it as you wish with your setData() function
       });

}
```

---

Note that with `doc.data().books` you are actually trying to get the `books` field of the user doc.